# Checking row count based on date range against date range

Tags: mysql, date, date-range

I'd like to ask you, if there is any way in mysql to do this. I know it can be done by cycle, but feeling like there has to be a better way.

I have table vacation

```
 id | date_from | date_to
 1   2017-02-16   2017-02-19
 2   2017-02-18   2017-02-21
 3   2017-02-12   2017-02-19
 4   2017-02-19   2017-02-21
```

The thing is, that user picks the date range he wants to reserve, like 2017-02-14 to 2017-02-24 and I have to check whether he can still request it, because only 4 people can request vacation simultaneously.

So I need query which will check whether in user selected range (for example 2017-02-14 to 2017-02-24) are for any day 4 or more rows.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I think we can do better than the answers provided below, but I think it would be useful to provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements, and an example of what a desired result might actually look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for any *day*:

```
select count(*)
from vacation v
where '2017-02-14' between date_from and date_to;
```

You can extend this to a range, by specifying each day:

```
select dte, count(v.id)
from (select date('2017-02-14') as dte union all
      select date('2017-02-15') as dte union all
      select date('2017-02-16') as dte union all
      select date('2017-02-17') as dte union all
      select date('2017-02-18') as dte union all
      . . .

     ) d left join
     vacation v
     on d.dte between date_from and date_to
group by d.dte
having count(*) > 4;
```

It might be simpler to loop through on the application side.  Or, to use a calendar table if you have one.

Comment: Thanks for answer, good idea. But you're right, application layer seems like better suited to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Select all rows in that date range and count the results:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM vacation WHERE :input_from BETWEEN date_from AND date_to OR :input_to BETWEEN date_from AND date_to
```

Comment: That will no give the result. For example, when applied to test case mentioned in the post, your query will only take the id 1,2,4, but all id's are involved. Furthermore, it will return sum of intersections in all days, but I need check intersection for each particular day...

Comment: I just changed my query, this way it should return all the vacations where a selected start time is in a current period or when the end time is in a current period. This way you should get all vacations in that range.

Comment: Yes, but still you can have 8 vacations in that range, but all days can be free (contain 3 or less vacations), that's the problem.